# Javascript error in WP7 webBrowser control!

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I need to develop a WP7 app, it has a Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser control, and i set it's loaded event as:

```
wb.IsScriptEnabled = true;  
string game_address = "http://192.168.1.26/start.html";
wb.Source = new Uri(game_address);
```

start.html is a HTML5 app, and when i run this app in the Emulator, this app is not run as well, but it's output any warming.

But I open this HTML5 app in the IE9 of Emulaor, it's work!

I develop a C# desktop application as a test. with the same webbrowser control and event code, it's give a javascript error alert "expected identifier, string or number" !
i set wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true, the error alert is not appear, but the HTML5 app still can't work!

And i can open this HTML5 app current in my windows IE9 and other browsers like chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post us the javascript and the error?

Different browsers deal with javascript differently. Possibly there is an error that is being handled by one browser but not by another. The browser on wp7 is unique to the phone.

Comment: javascript is a long and big file, it's a var that store a lot of strings, and i had checked all the ",".   the HTML5 is work on WP7 ie9 but not in the webbrowser control.

Answer (score 0):

If you also created a desktop application to test this then it wasnt "the webbrowser control and event code" as the browser on the phone is different.

`alert()` isn't supported in javascript on the phone. You should look to add different error reporting in your code to see what is going wrong.